# Value map field in query builder

Tags: qgis

My table contains integer field with value map defined in project. For example:
[image]

I can extract description with **represent_value()** function in expression:
[image]

But Query Builder does not support expressions. Is there any way to use description in Query builder?

Comment: With Query Builder are you referring to the Feature Filter in the Source menu?

Comment: The query builder use the syntax of the data provider and interact with the data as the provider level so as your value map seem to be set at the project level the query builder can't use it (I didn't try it but if you store your data in a gpkg and set a domain at the gpkg level then maybe you could find an expression that work...)

Comment: @Mayo, yes, I want to filter features by description, not by value. There are 2 different forms called Query Builder, but syntax is the same.

Comment: @J.R , thanks. My data source is geopackage file. Didn't know about geopackage  domains. Is it constraint like Esri domain? Not foreign keys? Anyway it is changing of data source. So, I cant use project level data in query.

Comment: Yes it's the same as esri domain, you need qgis 3.26 to use then in geopackage and 3.28 to use esri filegdb domain. https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-add-field-domain-management-capabilities-to-browser

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your expression as: represent_value("mapfield", 'One'). I hope that solves your problem. Otherwise the expression isn't valid.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately